# PHP preg_match results nothing local

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a simple preg_match statement...
When I test this on eg. regex101.com, everything that I want gets selected.
But when I set this to my script it brings nothing!

```
$params['filename'] = "2013-00049_20130830.pdf";
$pattern = '/([0-9]{4,8})/gm';
preg_match( $pattern, $params['filename'], $tmp);
print_r($tmp);
```

What I expact is an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013
    [1] => 00049
    [2] => 20130830
)
```

but there is not such thing... what am I doing wrong ???

Comment: No need to use `/gm` - use preg_match_all.

Comment: i tried without modifiers.. and also with preg_match_all, same result... only that ALL comes up with the error: `unknown modifire`

Comment: Are you sure [you tried everything](https://ideone.com/9MzFFc)?

Comment: omg... now it works... ... i just refreshed it about 15 times... *because of getting angry* now it works....

Comment: @Dwza : Magic!!  isn't ?

Comment: @Oxi : Yes it is. Its the same if you have a remotecontroll and battery is empty, if you press the button hard it will work (like squeezing out the battery) even if it makes no sence ^^